# What are some of the most compelling applications of Talagrand's concentration inequality?

Tags: combinatorics, concentration-of-measure

Many have praised [this inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talagrand's_concentration_inequality) as an incredibly awesome one. Can you point out a few problems where this inequality was crucial? I would especially appreciate the applications where the use of this inequality is easy to follow (such as for example, in combinatorics).

Answer (score 1):

In communication complexity: it is at the core of one of the proofs of the $\Omega(n)$ lower bound on the randomized communication complexity of **Gap-Hamming**, a problem that had remained open until 2010 (when it was first shown by Chakrabarti and Regev).

- Alexander A. Sherstov, [The Communication Complexity of Gap Hamming Distance](http://theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v008a008/) (2011)